# How to use methods not in CodeBehind via OnClick event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I want to reuse the same method for several pages, for example for a logout button or a redirect.
Right now i'm writing the same method in every codebehind page.

How can i do this? In PHP i just include a file with common functions and i have access to it, but what is the approach in ASP.NET?

```
    <asp:Button ID="logoutBtn" Text="Logout" runat="server"
CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="logoutBtn_Click" />
```

I want to access the method "logoutBtn_Click" from all pages in my project.

Comment: I suggest reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973803.aspx) to learn about inheritance and I suggest further readings into OOP.

Comment: Or maybe use a [masterpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX) - Then you will have it everywhere - just a idea

Comment: mAKE USE OF 3 TIER ARCHITECTURE....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create button click event handler method replica in app_code  class file like

```
namespace DotNetMirror
{
public class CommonClass
{
    public void CommonlogoutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //common logic code
    }
}
}
```

Designer file:

```
<asp:Button ID="logoutBtn" Text="Logout" runat="server"
        CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="logoutBtn_Click" />
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void logoutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DotNetMirror.CommonClass obj = new DotNetMirror.CommonClass();
    obj.CommonlogoutBtn_Click(sender, e);
}
```

You can have any number of button click events in pages but call the common method.

Comment: Could i make the class "CommonClass" static so i don't have make a new instance every time? So it's just: `CommonClass.logOut();` in the codebehind.

Comment: Yes you can do that, but don't add and use any static variables in that class

Answer (score 0):

You can use app_code folder. Create a `.cs` file there.

Write you method there and call that method form you all of the pages.

```
public class Class1
{
    public void abc()
    {
    }
 }
```

and use it like this

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.abc();
```

### Edit 1

Or you can use re-useable controls like [`user-controls`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET) or `custom-controls` and place it anywhere in you project.

Some basic examples

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87474/ASP-NET-Custom-Control

Comment: Could i make the class "Class1" static so i don't have make a new instance every time? So it's just: `Class1.logOut();` in the codebehind.

Comment: Depends on your condition. If you have only static data then you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

The way you include files in PHP, there are similar ways in ASP.NET(C#) to do that. 
You can make a class and then you can use that class anywhere in the project, on any page you want by creating an instance of that class.

For example:

```
Public Class logout
{
     public void logoutclick()
     {
        //your code goes here
     }
}
```

and now in the other page just create an instance of the class and use the function inside that class

```
logout log = new logout();
log.logoutclick();
```